# Angular UI Router - ui-view breaks bootstrap nested columns

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-router

I'm using ui-router and when rendering a template within `<ui-view />` the padding for nested columns is doubled. Is there a work around other than setting the padding to zero for nested cols?

```
<ui-view>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-9">
    Level 1: .col-sm-9
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-6">
        Level 2: .col-xs-8 .col-sm-6
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-6">
        Level 2: .col-xs-4 .col-sm-6
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</ui-view>

Level 1: .col-sm-9
  Level 2: .col-xs-8 .col-sm-6 Level 2: .col-xs-4 .col-sm-6
```

Should render as:

```
Level 1: .col-sm-9
Level 2: .col-xs-8 .col-sm-6 Level 2: .col-xs-4 .col-sm-6
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with a third party style sheet setting left and right margins to 0.